# How to remove unused attributes in java class in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am working in JAVA SE and I used netbeans pallete for creating JFrames. After some coding I saw my some frames have redundant unused attributes in unwriteable block:

for example

```
private javax.swing.JTextField methodNameField;
private javax.swing.JPanel methodsNamesTablePanel;
private javax.swing.JLabel nameLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel nameLabel1;
private javax.swing.JButton nextButton;
private javax.swing.JComboBox packagesComboBox2;   // unused
private javax.swing.JComboBox packagesComboBox3;   // unused
private javax.swing.JComboBox packagesComboBox6;   // unused
private javax.swing.JComboBox packagesComboBox7;   // unused
```

I dont have idea how to clean up? I can't select this part of code because netbeans pallete automatic create this part of code unwriteable. I trying use  Refactor -> Inspect and Transform but I don't find any there. Can anybody help with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your navigator. You should see "Other Components" in the component tree. You can delete them from there. Right click the component and delete

[image]

If you don't see this window, go to Window->Navigator. Make sure you're in the design view

Comment: i dont have nothing there. Is empty

Comment: What were the steps you took to get here? I mean have the unused components. I wanna check it out. Normally when you delete a component from the design view the component code is deleted also.

Comment: But if you drag components from the palette and you don't drag them onto the visual container, they end up in Other Components

Comment: What if other components doesn't give you the option to be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Just add any component to **Other components** and delete it. This will generate variables again;).